# How do i store a CSV file in variable as one big string

Tags: c++, csv

I want to achieve the same as this

```
std::string data = "1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1\n"
                   "2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2,2.2\n"
                   "3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3,3.3\n"
                   "4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4,4.4\n"
                   "5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5,5.5\n"
                   "6.6,6.6,6.6,6.6,6.6,6.6\n";
```

But where the variable data is stored from a .txt file.

I have accomplished it by doing this.

```
int main() {
   
    string inFileName = "data.txt";
    
    ifstream inFile;
    
    inFile.open(inFileName);
    
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        
        string line;
        
        while (inFile){
            getline(inFile, line);
            string newline = "\n";
            std::string data = line.append(newline);
            std::cout << data;
        }
        inFile.close();
    }

}
```

But i am not able to obtain the variable data outside the while loop.
So my question is how can i do this so i can use the data variable outside the while loop, so something like this will work?

```
int main() {
   
    string inFileName = "data.txt";
    
    ifstream inFile;
    
    inFile.open(inFileName);
    
    if(inFile.is_open()){
        
        string line;
        
        while (inFile){
            getline(inFile, line);
            string newline = "\n";
            std::string data = line.append(newline);
            
        }
        inFile.close();
    }
    std::cout << data;
}
```

Comment: Does your C++ textbook has an example of using `+=` with a `std::string`, that you can use as a template for implementing your program? This is how you combine text strings together, so you'd use it to combine each line from your file, as you read it in, into a single text string. Mission accomplished!

Comment: `std::ifstream inFile(inFileName); std::ostringstream ss; ss << inFile.rdbuf(); std::string data = ss.str();`

Comment: Why do you want to store a CSV file into a string? Is it necessary?  Common method is to store the items (records) into a database (in memory or in an actual database).  Storing into a string doesn't really provide benefit, as you now have to read into a string then parse the string; rather than just parsing as you are reading the file.

Comment: It is because i am using the strtk::token_grid from http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html#TokenGrid so i needed it on that form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variables are in the wrong scope:

```
std::string data;
if(inFile.is_open())
{
    while (inFile)
    {
        std::string line;
        getline(inFile, line);
        data += line+"\n";
    }
    inFile.close();
}
std::cout << data;
```